# Start service delay after boot

Tags: java, android, service, delay, startup

I have a classic `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` app which activates with a service on startup. But it starts after i started to use my phone (1 or 2 min later). I want to execute it before user starts using the phone especially like screen lock. How can i minimize that period? 
I tried `android.intent.category.HOME` and `android:priority="1000"` but no effect. Also i have root privileges, i can use shell command or script.
I would appreciate any help.